# Bootstrap 2.3.2 Responsive Navbar Not Covering Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I have a navigation bar in Bootstrap 2.3.2 that looks great on desktop. I am trying to use the responsive navbar for tablets and mobile and I am having some issues. The navbar code I am using is pretty standard

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

        <!-- dynamic code builds the menu here -->

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am overwriting the standard css just to provide a different look & feel. Here is the relevant CSS.

```
.navbar {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight: 200; 
    margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    height:40px;
}

.navbar-inner, .navbar-inner .container {
    background-color: #004080;
    border-color: #6699cc;
    background-image: none;
}

.navbar .nav > li > a, .navbar .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar .nav > li > a:visited {
    text-shadow: none;
    color:#fff;
}

.navbar .nav li.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
a.menu:after, .dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    font-size:11px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top:-5px !important;
}
```

The problem I have is when you click on the button to collapse the menu on a tablet or phone the content behind the navigation is still visible. This makes it very hard to see the menu items. Any idea how I can make the menu non transparent or to push the content down? You can see from the pictures I attached what it looks like off and then on when you click the navigation collapse button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to set `z-index` property

Comment: You should post the CSS you've applied.

Comment: Check your css. Your background is probably transparent. Search for opacity or some background color rgba

Comment: Sorry about that.. updated the post with the css I am using. It is really just giving the menu a custom look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

The affix plugin in bootstrap will be a perfect handler for your menu/navbar. It will collapse and expand the menu responsively based on the screen size. So you don't have to worry about managing the css and javascript to expand and collapse menu.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
```

The `data-spy`attribute will add the plugin to your code and the `data-offset-top` attribute says when the navbar should be changed to fixed. In the example above, the navbar will become fixed after scrolling 100px. When the menu is expanded or collapsed the plugin will push the content down or pull it back to the original position respectively.

To make your menu non transparent and precede on top of all the contents in the page add the following css to your navbar.

```
.navbar{
  opacity : 1;
  z-index : 10;//a value greater than any other page contents' z-index
}
```

Comment: I see what the affix plugin does now. I don't think I really need anything like that for this project but its good to know you can do that so Thank you! In the case of the menu the opacity is already at 1 which is why I don't understand how you can see text below it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow what a fail on my part. So the problem was I had a height set in navbar class so when the menu expanded it stayed to a fixed height. Removing that height attribute now allows the menu to expand down like it should. Sorry for the blunder and thanks for helping me solving it friends. Paired Programming FTW.

[image]